# Python компиляция проекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, компиляция, проект

Имеется два приложения. 
 1. Парсер получающий входящие данные через консоль 
 2. Парсер с интерфейсом QT

Необходимо скомпилировать два данных варианта под Windows\Linux\FreeBSD (что бы не устанавливать Python + библиотеки на разные машины). В первую очередь интересует Windows. Писалось все под Ubuntu 15.10, Python 3.4.

Если с C# понятно как сделать, то в случае с Python нет.

Как я понял проект необходимо было создавать проект в виртуальном окружении, устанавливая туда необходимые библиотеки (urllib, lxml, qt), у меня же это делалось без виртуального изолированного окружения, в одном файле parser.py с импортом библиотек как обычно.

Каков ход действий, команд, для компиляции в исполняемый файл что бы приложение запускалось без установки python\qt и других библиотек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую для таких целей [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). На выходе получается исполняемый файл с кучкой всего, что ему необходимо. [Документация](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/), вроде, понятная.
Существует еще популярный [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Немного о ["Freezing Your Code"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/).

Comment: В некоторых случаях можно буквально скомпилировать Питон код: http://compilers.pydata.org/